# Cómo coger datos de dos tablas (MySQL y MS Access) y guardarlos en una matriz para compararlos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Quiero coger datos de dos bases de datos que se encuentran en distintos servidores (una MySQL y otra MS Access), guardarlas en dos matrices (cada una en una) y compararlas, para cuando haya un dato distinto, que consulte a un sistema de logs que, con la fecha guardada de cada cambio (no tengo ni idea de cómo implementarlo), me permita sincronizar el cambio más reciente. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer esto? Gracias.

Comment: De entrada tendrías que conectar a cada  una de las bases de datos, extraer los datos, guardarlos en dos variables y a partir de ahí combinarlas, compararlas o hacer lo que haya que hacer. Empieza por ahí y si tienes algún problema puedes preguntar aquí concretamente. Tu pregunta tal y como está planteada ahora no se adapta al formato del sitio, te falta un punto de partida.

Comment: Pues por ejemplo no sé ni cómo empezar por lo primero, que es guardar los datos de una tabla en una variable que sea una matriz.

Comment: Según la API que uses para conectar a cada base de datos (PDO, mysqli, una API propia de Microsoft en el caso de la BD de Access ...), cada una tiene sus métodos para leer resultados de consultas y guardarlos en variables. Eso está explicado en la documentación, tanto del Manual de PHP como de Microsoft (en el caso de Access). Ese es uno de los motivos por el cual **no podemos ayudarte sin un punto de partida**, porque ni siquiera sabemos que API usas, qué tienes instalado en tu entorno, etc. Te toca a ti decirlo, ensayar un código y si tienes errores concretos entonces te ayudaremos.

Comment: Puede que para este caso tengas que plantear varias preguntas (todas las que quieras si fuera necesario) pero adaptadas al formato del sitio. Te propongo que empieces por lo primero: conexión a c/ BD y guardar resultados en varibales. Empieza haciendo eso por separado, leyendo la documentación y cualquier problema lo planteas aquí, mostrando el código, los errores que tienes, etc. Puede que por ejemplo tengas problemas conectando a una de las BD y no a otra, entonces puedes preguntar aquí sobre eso y si tienes problemas con las dos BD tendrás que hacer dos preguntas sólo para el tema conexión